# Open connected subsets of path-connected spaces

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a path-connected topological space and $Y$ an open connected subset. Is $Y$ path-connected?

Comment: Not equivalent, but related:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766422/when-does-open-and-connected-imply-path-connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve), together with a path linking the two endpoints.  Then $X$ is path-connected but deleting a point (other than the origin) yields a space that is connected but not path-connected.

Comment: As an observation, note that the assumption of locally path-connectedness on $X$ would imply a positive result: since then you would be able to prove that a path-connected component of $Y$ would be both open.