# Open connected subsets of path connected spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, path-connected

Does every open and connected subset of path connected topological space has to be path connected? Statement should be false as there is a similar theorem but for Euclidean spaces, however I can't think of a counterexample. What about the same statement, but for path connected metric spaces?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766422/when-does-open-and-connected-imply-path-connected

Comment: An open and connected subset of a *locally* path-connected space is path-connected. This is the theorem I think you are confused with.

Answer (score 4):

The classical example of a connected (metric) space that is not path-connected is the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve). I will give an example based on this.

Consider the graph of the $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ function on $(0,1]$.
[image]

Let $X$ be the space which consists of this graph together with the vertical line segment connecting $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$, and the curve in red:[image]

$X$ is a metric space that is path connected. You can also clearly see this as an open subset of $X$:

[image]

This is an open connected subspace of the $X$ that is not path connected.

This counter example is a metric space. It applies as well for the general case of topological spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the space $$X=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, (x=0\land y\le 2)\lor \left(x\ne 0\land y=\sin\frac1{\lvert x\rvert}\right) \lor (y\ge 0\land x^2+y^2=4)\right\}$$

I.e. a topologist sine, plus an appropriate vertical half-line, plus a half circle "path-connecting" the curve to the tip of the half-line. Then, $X\setminus \{(0,2)\}$ is connected, but not path-connected.