# Doubt in connected and path connected s

Tags: calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

My teacher taught me that a set of points is connected if and only if it is path connected. However,the Topologist's sine curve is connected but not path connected. Am i missing something here?

Comment: This is only true if we put extra conditions on the space in question. For instance, a locally path connected space is connected iff it is path connected. Generally though there are connected spaces that are not path connected as you point out.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: If the set is open then it is path connected

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi yes, for **open** subsets of the plane because these are locally path-connected. And the Topologist's sine curve is closed and not-open.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma does open connected subset of $ \mathbb{R}^n$ is not neccesarily path connected

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi for an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ we have that it’s connected iff it’s path-connected. That might be the fact your teacher was referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your teacher is wrong. Even for planar subsets connected does **not** imply path-connected. In $\Bbb R$ this equivalence *does* hold, maybe you misheard him and did he mean that instead. Otherwise just plain wrong. Within the class of locally path-connected spaces the equivalence does hold, though. So e.g. in $\Bbb C$, the regions/domains (open connected subsets) are also path-connected (even with piecewise linear paths) which becomes important for path-integration theory.

Answer (score 0):

In general, path-connected implies connected. The converse is not true as you point out with the topologist's sine curve. As Henno is correctly pointing out, the notion is equivalent ***in $\mathbb{R}$*** since the topology in $\mathbb{R}$ is "so poor" that it is impossible to find a non-path-connected set that is connected. To be able to find one, you need to go on "bigger" topological spaces, in some sense.

I suggest that you go [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766422/when-does-open-and-connected-imply-path-connected) to see how far you can generalize the equivalence, where it is noticed that in a locally path-connected space, connected open sets are path-connected. Every topological vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is locally path-connected since the balanced neighbourhoods form a local base at 0.